# how to set up routes in backbone based off id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am trying to set up routes for a SPA using backbone. What I want to do is to have a user type in a url, ex http: //......#/image_sets/1 that will then execute a GET request that returns the image set with id 1 from the API database. What I cant seem to figure out is how to pass the id that the user enters in the url to the GET request. I am also wondering if I have set up my routes correctly so that I can display the individual image sets? Thanks.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'home',
        'users': 'users', // users does not exist
        'images': 'images',
        'comments': 'comments',
        'likes': 'likes',
        'postImages': 'postImages',
        'image_sets/:id' : 'image_sets'
    },


image_sets: function(id) {
        $('#content').empty();
        $('#myCarousel').hide();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://pixelect-rails-api.herokuapp.com/image_sets/id', 
            type: 'GET'
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var template = Handlebars.compile($('#imageSetsTemplate').html());
              $('#content').html(template({
                image_set: response
            }));
        });
    },
```

Comment: Concatenate the `id` on to the URL string: url: `'https://pixelect-rails-api.herokuapp.com/image_sets/' + id`,

Comment: Thanks that worked although now I get an error of 'Uncaught Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined' on the line 'var template = Handlebars.compile($('#imageSetsTemplate').html());' -- any ideas about this?

Comment: Two things are possible. The element doesn't exist-->double check. Or, the DOM isn't ready. In which case wrap everything in `$(function() {});`

Comment: I figured it out, had a typo of the template id, thanks for your help tho.